# Break the login code test

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

I saw some where like they used code like

```
login=' or 1=1 -- & password=' or 1=1 --
```

to login to sites from front end. I was wondering how this code used to break the login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example given by you exploits badly thought out code, where user input is not escaped and used in queries.
Let's say there is a form with user and password fields (form.html), which passes values entered to php script (test.php). Assume user writes **'' OR 1 =1--** in both fields

Code below does not escape user input. You should use mysql_real_escape_string() or parameterized queries to do that.

form.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
    <input type="text" name="login" value=""><br />
    <input type="text" name="password" value=""><br />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

test.php:

```
$name = $_POST['login'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
echo $name . "<br />";
$sql= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = $name AND password = $pass ";
// $sql now contains this command:
// SELECT * FROM users WHERE login= '' OR 1=1-- AND password = '' OR 1 =1-- 
// condition OR 1=1 means that any row satisfies the query
// as long as there is at least 1 row in the table users, authorisation will be succcesful
echo $sql . "<br />";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is SQL injection.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection